# Include "in-depth" slides in beamer presentation, depending on course

Tags: beamer, keywords

actually, I'm preparing lectures for **two courses (--> Course 1, Course 2)** at my university.

The overall topic and "storyline" is the **same for both courses**. So let's assume it looks like this:

```
Lecture Overview
    Topic 1
        Topic Foo slides
        Topic Bar slides
    Topic 2
        Topic Foo slides
        Topic Bar slides
```

Due to **different specializations**, there are some topics I need to elaborate with Course 1 in detail and some other to elaborate with Course 2 in detail:

```
Lecture Overview
    Topic 1
        Topic Foo slides
            In-depth slides for Course 1
        Topic Bar slides
            In-depth slides for Course 1
            In-depth slides for Course 2
    Topic 2
        Topic Foo slides
            In-depth slides for Course 1
            In-depth slides for Course 2
        Topic Bar slides
            In-depth slides for Course 2
```

So when creating a slide, I would like to be able to specify

- If it is shown in the presentation for BOTH courses (default behavior)
- If it is shown especially in the presentation of Course 1
- If it is shown especially in the presentation of Course 2

However, a more general solution where I could classify some slides as "in-depth" / "adavanced" slides, including them in a way like e.g.

```
 Lecture Course n
     \include{some_topic}
```

for general slides and e.g.

```
 Lecture Course n
     \include{some_topic}{advanced}
```

for general slides PLUS advanced slides would be absolutely sufficient.

Could not find anything like that skimming the beamer manual and using google. Don't want to exclude the possibility that I'm searching for the wrong keywords...

Comment: Have a look at the beameraudience package